# Force Excel to exclude UID in connection string on ODBC Data Connection?

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc

I have several Excel reports that query an Oracle database via ODBC that I share with other users. Each user has their own user ID and password that is saved in their `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ODBC/ODBC.INI` file to make connecting to these databases easier.

Each time I add a query to Excel, Excel automatically creates a connection string that can be executed each time the data needs to be refreshed in Excel.
The connection string is of the form:

> DSN=DATABASE;UID=USERNAME;DBQ=DBASE;DBA=W;APA=T;EXC=F;FEN=T;QTO=T;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;BTD=F;BNF=F;BAM=IfAllSuccessful;NUM=NLS;DPM=F;MTS=T;MDI=F;CSR=F;FWC=F;FBS=64000;TLO=O;MLD=0;ODA=F;”

I want Excel to exclude the `UID=USERNAME` parameter from these connection strings that it builds so that it will pull the username from the registry instead. It currently does this for the password value, but not the username.

If I manually delete the UID parameter, Excel automatically fills it in again each time the query is refreshed and fills it in with which ever user last refreshed the query:

[image: Connection String Dialog]

I’ve tried filling in the username as `UID=/`, which seems to tell Excel to pull the username from the registry like I want it to the first time it’s run; but subsequently, the Oracle ODBC Driver Connect login pops up thinking that the username is actually `/`:

[image: Oracle Connect Dialog]

So it seems Oracle or doesn’t recognize this parameter consistently.

Basically I’m trying to find out if there’s some kind of wildcard or other parameter like this that I can use to fill in for the UID field so that both Excel and the Oracle ODBC Driver Connect dialog know to go and pull the username from the registry; or if there’s a way to prevent Excel from adding the UID parameter to a connection string each time a connection is refreshed.

If not, I’m thinking my solution may be to build an Excel add-on that automatically deletes the UID field whenever Excel tries to add it to a connection string.

Comment: Record a macro while you enter password. Then you should get the VBA code to make it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was to split the connection string into an array, clear the element that began with "UID=", and put the connection string back together.